# ServiceStack OrmLite AutoQuery Filter

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, autoquery-servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

Should the following work:  `?OpensContains=Something` by querying the Name column on the db?  It doesn't and I'm not sure why not?

```
 [QueryDbField(Field = "Name")]
 public string OpensContains { get; set; }
```

`?NameContains=Something` does work, the column exists, I was assuming that I could add a different Property to the request object that would query the same field using contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're customizing the field you need to provide the template otherwise it defaults to an `=` operand, i.e:

```
[QueryDbField(Field = "Name", Template = "{Field} LIKE {Value}", ValueFormat = "%{0}%")]
```

Comment: Confirmed that worked though I don't recall reading that in the documentation.  Thanks.